# Can I return this sql query on one line?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to query some info and have it display on one line. What I have is Tax info for my clients. I am looking to return the company name and the number of state filings and the number of county filings we do for them. I get an error asking me to include 'description' and 'tcode' in my group by but when I do that I only get 1 as a count. Also i'm getting several rows of info and it ends up showing like this

```
co  StateFilingCount    LocalFilingCount
Co  NULL    NULL
Co  NULL    1
Co  1   NULL


SELECT DISTINCT CT.co, 
CASE WHEN description LIKE '%SITW' THEN COUNT(tcode) END AS StateFilingCount, 
CASE WHEN tcode LIKE '__-%' THEN COUNT(tcode) END AS LocalFilingCount FROM CTax CT
WHERE tcode NOT LIKE 'ss-%' AND CT.endDate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY CT.co
ORDER BY CT.co ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier with a SQL fiddle but I'll take a shot:

```
SELECT
    CT.co, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN description LIKE '%SITW' THEN tcode END) AS StateFilingCount, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tcode LIKE '__-%' THEN tcode END) AS LocalFilingCount
FROM CTax CT
WHERE tcode NOT LIKE 'ss-%' AND CT.endDate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY CT.co
ORDER BY CT.co ASC
```

I would trying moving the `COUNT` to outside the `CASE` statement. You should also be able to get rid of the `DISTINCT` since you're doing a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Note that this answer if functionally equivalent to @DStanley's answer, it just takes advantage of the fact that `CASE` will return `NULL` if the `WHEN` condition isn't met, and that `COUNT` ignores `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a subgroup count.  One way to do it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CT.co, 
SUM(CASE WHEN description LIKE '%SITW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StateFilingCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN tcode LIKE '__-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LocalFilingCount 
FROM CTax CT
WHERE tcode NOT LIKE 'ss-%' 
    AND CT.endDate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY CT.co
ORDER BY CT.co ASC
```